# Buscar coincidencias por campos -Mogoose-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

me encuentro usando node~express~mongoose y recibo por request un objeto como este:

```
{
    carro:"azul",
    moto:"rojo"
}
```

La intención es validar que no se inserten valores que ya existan en las claves de los documentos existentes, todos deben ser únicos *(si existiera al menos un valor repetido entre el objeto y un documento, se descarta el registro)*, y para esto consulto la bd y así responder con el documento que se esta duplicando y descartarlo:

```
const query = await vehRegister.find(
    {
        $or:[
            {"carro":azul}, //Error si existe azul
            {"moto":rojo}  // o error si existe rojo
        ]
    }
)
```

También:

```
const vehiculos = Object.entries(req.body).map((k,i)=> ({
    [k[0]]: k[1]
}))
const query = await vehRegister.find(
    {
        $or:vehiculos
    }
)
```

Esquema

```
const vehiculoSchema = new Schema({ 
        carro:{type:String},
        moto:{type:String}
    })
```

Pero esto no funciona para mi. ¿Qué alternativa puedo seguir? Agradezco el aporte

Comment: Puedes crear una clave de unicidad sobre los dos campo, de esta forma se garantiza que nunca se repita una combinación de ambas.

Comment: quizas fue un error de escritura... pero depronto no te funciona porque el azul y el rojo de la consulta `$or` de arriba deben ir entre comillas {"carro":"azul"}